# Algorithm to zero pad data before FFT

Tags: fft, algorithms, python, c

I've seen some other questions on here about zero padding (like [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/how-to-resample-audio-using-fft-or-dft/) one) but I'm still a little confused about my situation.

I'm attempting to zero pad my input time series data, so I get an interpolated frequency spectrum. I had initially tried this with NumPy's FFT package, and I checked my algorithm on generated data to see if it works. I generated sine waves of known frequencies, and checked to see what the differences were between the actual, unpadded and padded estimates for frequencies. For frequencies that sat exactly in an FFT bin, the unpadded and padded estimates agreed exactly (as they should).

But I need to implement this in C (using the FFTW library), but the same test fails in the algorithm I implemented. What I'm doing is -

- Read in time series (generated data)
- Perform unpadded FFT, obtain frequency estimate (by looking at the bin with the maximum amplitude)
- To the end of the time series, add zeros (I'm using 10 times as many zeros).
- Take an FFT of the padded array, and obtain frequency estimate.
- Compare the two frequency estimates.

Turns out the two frequency estimates are very different. This is because in my C code, there seem to be multiple places where the value of the FFT matches the maximum.

I think this is because of how I'm padding zeros to the array.
**Question:** How does one correctly pad zeros to an array such that the FFT yields similar results to the unpadded array?

---

**EDIT:** Relevant code (Python and C)

Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
PI = np.pi

ixFreq = 10.0    # This is the bin that will have the max
iyFreq = 10.0    # amplitude in the fourier plane

xSize  = 24      # Define the size of the array
ySize  = 60

xPeriod = xSize/ixFreq # Calculate what the period needs to be 
yPeriod = ySize/iyFreq

xxFreq  = 1./xPeriod # This is the *actual* frequency.
yyFreq  = 1./yPeriod

padFac  = 10         # Padding factor
xPad    = padFac * xSize
yPad    = padFac * ySize

npt     = xSize * ySize
padnpt  = xPad * yPad

xy      = np.mgrid[0:ySize,0:xSize] # 2D grid to generate the sine wave

data    = np.sin(2.0*PI * (xy[0]/yPeriod + xy[1]/xPeriod)) # Sine wave

dFFT    = np.fft.fft2(data) # Regular (unpadded) FFT
padFFT  = np.fft.fft2(data, s=[yPad,xPad]) # Padded FFT

freqArr = np.fft.fftfreq(ySize) # Frequency bins
freqPad = np.fft.fftfreq(yPad)

datmax  = np.amax(np.abs(dFFT[:,:xSize/2])) # Find magnitude and pos of max val
datwhere = np.where(np.abs(dFFT[:,:xSize/2]) == datmax)
padmax  = np.amax(np.abs(padFFT[:,:xPad/2]))
padwhere = np.where(np.abs(padFFT[:,:xPad/2]) == padmax)

freqD = freqArr[datwhere[0][0]]
freqP = freqPad[padwhere[0][0]]

print "Actual Freq: % 5.5lf" % yyFreq # Print everything out
print "Data Max: % 5.5lf" % (np.amax(data))
print "FFT Max: % 5.5lf  Where: % 5.5lf\n" % (datmax/np.sqrt(npt), freqD)
print "Pad Max: % 5.5lf  Where: % 5.5lf\n" % (padmax/np.sqrt(npt), freqP)
```

C:
Note - I've used a few user written functions, but I've tested them and I'm fairly certain that they're not the problem. I'm including them in here so you guys have a working piece of code, though.
How I compiled it - `gcc -Wall -o "fftwTest" fftwTest.c -lfftw3 -lm`

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <complex.h>
# include <fftw3.h>

#define LARGENUMBER 9999999
#define BADDATA -999999

void fftFreqD(int len, double d, double *freqArr)
{
   // Calculate given the bin, what the frequency is. Equivalent of 
   // numpy's fftfreq function
   int      ii;

   freqArr[0] = 0.;            //zero bin is always DC component

   if (len % 2 == 0){          // If length of even size
      for(ii = 1; ii < len/2; ii++)
         freqArr[ii] = ii/(d*len);
      for(ii = len/2; ii < len; ii++)
         freqArr[ii] = -(len-ii)/(d*len);
   }
   else{                      // Else if odd size
      for(ii = 1; ii < (floor(len/2)+1); ii++)
         freqArr[ii] = ii/(d*len);
      for(ii = (floor(len/2)+1); ii < len; ii++)
         freqArr[ii] = -(len-ii)/(d*len);
   }

   return;
}


void minmaxArrayC(int indx1, int indx2, complex *data, double *mindata,
                                                              double *maxdata)
{
   // Find the minimum and maximum value of a complex array, by taking
   // the absolute value
   int ii;

   *mindata = LARGENUMBER;
   *maxdata = BADDATA;
   for (ii = indx1; ii < indx2; ii++) {
      if (*mindata > cabs(data[ii]))
          *mindata = cabs(data[ii]);
      if (*maxdata < cabs(data[ii]))
          *maxdata = cabs(data[ii]);
   }
}   

void generate2DSin(double *outarr,double amp,double freqx, double freqy, 
                                              double phase,int lenx, int leny)
{
   int ii, jj, index=0;
   for(ii = 0; ii < lenx; ii++){
      for(jj = 0; jj < leny; jj++) 
         index = ii*leny + jj;
         outarr[index] = amp * sin(2.0*M_PI*(freqx*ii+freqy*jj) + phase);
   }
   return;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   int              xSize = 24, ySize = 60;
   int              padx, pady, padfac;
   int              npt, padnpt;
   int              ii, jj, index;

   double           *data, maxfft, maxpad, posmax=0, posmaxpad=0;
   double           *paddata;
   double           dum;
   double           xf, yf, ixf, iyf, xpd, ypd;
   double           *freqArr, *freqArrPad;

   fftw_complex     *fftdata, *padfft;
   fftw_plan        t2f, t2pad;

   ixf       = 10.0; // The bin that will have max amplitude in the fourier
   iyf       = 10.0; // plane. 

   xpd       = xSize/ixf; // The period of the wave, in the x and y directions
   ypd       = ySize/iyf;

   xf       = 1./xpd; // The actual frequency of the wave
   yf       = 1./ypd;

   padfac    = 32;
   pady   = padfac * ySize;
   padx   = padfac * xSize;

   padnpt    = pady * padx;
   npt       = xSize * ySize;
   data      = calloc(npt, sizeof(*data));
   fftdata   = calloc(npt, sizeof(*fftdata));
   freqArr   = calloc(npt, sizeof(*freqArr));
   padfft    = calloc(padnpt, sizeof(*padfft));
   paddata   = calloc(padnpt, sizeof(*paddata));
   freqArrPad = calloc(padnpt, sizeof(*freqArrPad));

   t2f     = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(xSize, ySize, data, fftdata, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
   t2pad   = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(padx,pady,paddata,padfft,FFTW_ESTIMATE);

   generate2DSin(data, 1., xf, yf, 0., xSize, ySize);

   for(ii = 0; ii < ySize; ii++) {
      for(jj = 0; jj < xSize; jj++) {
         index = ii * xSize + jj;
         paddata[index] = data[index];
      }
   }
   for(ii = ySize; ii < pady; ii++) {
      for(jj = xSize; jj < padx; jj++) {
         index = ii*padx + jj;
         paddata[index] = 0.;
      }
   }

   fftw_execute(t2f);
   fftw_execute(t2pad);

   minmaxArrayC(0, npt, fftdata, &dum, &maxfft);
   minmaxArrayC(0, padnpt, padfft, &dum, &maxpad);

   fftFreqD(ySize, 1, freqArr);
   fftFreqD(pady, 1, freqArrPad);

   for(ii = 0; ii < ySize; ii++){
      for(jj = 0; jj < xSize; jj++) {
         index = ii*xSize + jj;
         if(cabs(fftdata[index]) == maxfft){
            posmax = freqArr[ii];
         }
      }
   }
   for(ii = 0; ii < pady; ii++){
      for(jj = 0; jj < padx; jj++) {
         index = ii*padx + jj;
         if(cabs(padfft[index]) == maxpad)
            posmaxpad = freqArrPad[ii];
      }
   }

   printf("FFT Max: % 5.5lf Where: % 5.5lf\n", maxfft, posmax);
   printf("pad Max: % 5.5lf Where: % 5.5lf\n", maxpad, posmaxpad);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to show  us some of the code (say the equivalent bits of Python and C)? Also, why are you doing so much padding? Usually the padding is from the end of your data to the nearest power of the radix of your FFT (e.g 2).

Comment: I'll edit in my code shortly! I'm padding for interpolation rather than to get a power of two FFT. I (perhaps naively) assumed that a larger amount of padding will give me better interpolation in the fourier domain.

Comment: If you want to interpolate, you'll need to (low pass) filter and downsample - that may be the cause of your difficulties.

Comment: @Kitchi You are correct in your assumption that increasing the padding will also increase your resolution in the frequency domain. This result is easier to see when you think in terms of the DFT rather than the FFT.

Comment: @TomKealy  I don't think that low-pass filtering and downsampling will give the desired result in this case. Upsampling and low-pass filtering will also not be helpful because the peaks of the FFT will not move to their correct locations as a result of these operations. I think that Kitchi has the right idea here, there is just something amiss in the implementation, or in the interpretation of the results.

Comment: @TomKealy - Added in code... apologies for the C code being so large, I wanted to post a working example. I've tried to comment it to be clear, but please let me know if I need to provide any more information!

Comment: I had to add `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-fpermissive"` in order to suppress a bunch of errors related to variable typing.  Also, the function `generate2DSin` is missing, and you have a mismatched bracket problem (I think it is missing  around line 132).  Can you try building your example code in isolation to make sure that it compiles, and then repost?

Comment: I made a rough translation of your C code to matlab, and I verified that the *algorithm* is sound.  In other words, I am fairly certain that this is a problem with your implementation and not your high-level approach.  One of the problems in your C implementation that may be causing you grief is that the function `generate2DSin` fills the array in a **column-wise** fashion, and then the subsequent for-loop reads it back out in a **row-wise** fashion.  Since the 2D array is not square, this is a big problem.  You might want to check all of your code for consistency in this regard.

Comment: @nispio - That's exactly what I figured as well! That, and an indexing issue. But otherwise the algorithm itself is working fine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Zero-padding data (that has not been previously non-rectangularly windowed) adds more visible rectangular window artifacts to non-periodic-in-aperture signals.  You might be looking at all the local maxima of the ripples of the resulting Sinc function, which are alongside a main lobe maxima.

Comment: I'm hunting for the largest value in the spectrum, and looking at the corresponding bin. If it's the sidelobes that I'm looking at, they won't be as large as the main lobe no?

Comment: The two negations are somehow confusing. Zero-padding works only if you have applied any window that fades out the signal to zero. Just cutting out the signal (rectangular window) creates an edge on the continuation point, which will distrub the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

There are instances when some care must be taken when zero padding (ie preservation of signal parity).  However, it doesn't seem like it should make a difference in your problem.

There are two things I can think of that might affect your result, or at least your interpretation of the result. The first is scaling; zero padding will affect the average power of your signal. The second is that depending on the number of zeros you choose to add to the end, you can alter the locations of the bin centers.

The MATLAB code below shows an example of what one might expect to see when zero-padding to improve FFT granularity.  Notice that both the peak location and peak amplitude become *more accurate* in the zero-padded version.

```
Fs = 48e3;                          % Sampling rate (Hz)
f0 = 5e3;                           % Center frequency
N = 2^7;                            % Samples in time series
K = 8;                              % Zero-pad factor

% Generate N time indices
t = (0:N-1)/Fs;

% Create a sinusoid signal of length N*Fs at f0 Hz
x = cos(2*pi*f0*t)/N;

% Create a zero-padded version of x
xpad = [x, zeros(1,(K-1)*length(x))];

% Helper function for plotting FFT
plotFFT=@(x,N,Fs,spec) plot(Fs*(0:N-1)/N-Fs/2, abs(fftshift(fft(x))),spec);

% Plot padded FFT vs unpadded FFT
figure(1);
plotFFT(xpad,length(xpad),Fs,'b'); hold on;
plotFFT(x,length(x),Fs,'-ro'); hold off;
title('Padded vs. Unpadded FFT'); legend('Padded FFT','Unpadded FFT');
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('abs( X(f) )');
```

[image: Padded vs. Unpadded FFT]

Comment: Good overall answer, but "when zero-padding to improve FFT resolution" is not true. To increase _resolution_ you need to take a larger number of samples into the FFT. A better term would be to say it increases [frequency _granularity_](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/fft-frequency-resolution/10239#10239).

Comment: @user4619  Hmmm. While I see your point, I disagree somewhat with your correction.  The only time when zero-padding will not increase the resolution, is when the FFT size does not change.  Can you take an N-FFT of a zero-padded signal of length N*K, without first reducing the number of samples back down to N, and effectively removing the zero-padding? Note that I did not say "zero-padding improves FFT resolution," rather "when zero-padding to improve FFT resolution."  I never said that the zero-padding itself would increase the resolution, only that such was the end goal of the zero padding.

Comment: I think what @user4619 is trying to say is that zero padding adds no new information, it just increases the density of bins across the peak. But two close peaks that weren't resolved in the original FFT won't be resolved in the zero-padded FFT.

Comment: @user4619 and Kitchi  Point taken.  However, in the example above, if I add a second tone to my signal at 5.3 kHz I only see one peak in the N-point FFT.  However, zero padding will allow me to discern two distinct peaks.  What terminology would you use to account for this?  Because I am now able to distinguish two distinct signals that I could not previously distinguish, my inclination would be to still say that I experienced an increase in my ability to resolve frequencies, or "resolution."

Comment: Nispio, "What terminology would you use to account for this? ". The proper terminology here would be to say that you did a better peak-picking after _interpolating_ the samples, _via_ zero-padding. _Resolution_ has to do with main-lobe width, which has not changed.

Comment: An intuitive example: If I took a blurry picture of a sun-set, and then up-sampled it, did I increase its resolution? No. Why not? Because I did not add any new information. My new image based on the new grid size was filled using a linear combination of points from the previous grid. This is in contrast to filling in samples on the new grid mesh originally. (aka, higher pixel count camera, for example).

Comment: @user4619  I agree with the concepts put forth in your example.  However, your example does not address my question.  When I zero-pad, I am able to see two distinct peaks in the FFT near 5 kHz and 5.3 kHz, whereas before zero -padding I was only able to see one peak.  What terminology would you use to explain this result?

Comment: @nispio.  Peak separation resolution does not increase with FFT length, only data length.  Either the 2nd peak is actually an illusion, or perhaps your interpolation before zero-padding was poor quality (not a Sinc).

Comment: Hidden would be a better word than illusion.  With no 3 dB gap between to validate.

Comment: I guess I should start a new topic to discuss this, since there is something that is obvious to everyone but me.

Comment: @nispio It would make a good question, feel free to ask it here. About the specific example like I said, you can say that "Two peaks were visible after interpolation".

Comment: @nispio agree with you. plese post your question with appropriate plots.