# Frequency range for STFT in Librosa

Tags: python, stft

I am currently looking at the STFT for Librosa. I was wondering how to understand the output of the STFT function, specifically what kind of frequencies the different values represent.

Say I have a *n_fft* of 256, that means that the shape output of the STFT will be 129 (*1+n_fft/2*). I therefore understand that for each frame I have 129 bins, these bins represent some sort of frequency within this frame. I am assuming that the bins start with a frequency of 0hz and go up to some value, with each bin representing an equally large range.

But how do I figure out what the maximum frequency used for STFT is? And what about the range of each of the 129 bins?

Just to be clear, I have tried looking at the source-code and at the documentation, but I have not really become much wiser.

Comment: have a look on this question: [FFT resolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10236/fft-frequency-resolution)

Comment: So if my sampling frequency is 16000, and I have 129 bins, then the resolution is ~124, meaning that each of the bins has a frequency range of 124? Is that a correct way of looking at it?

Answer (score 1):

Having a look into the sources of [`librosa.display.specshow`](https://librosa.org/librosa/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html) reveals how bins are converted into frequencies internally: The plotting uses [`librosa.core.fft_frequencies`](https://librosa.org/librosa/generated/librosa.core.fft_frequencies.html), which shows that it is basically the same as [`numpy.fft.fftfreq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html):

```
>>> librosa.fft_frequencies(sr=22050, n_fft=16)
array([     0.   ,   1378.125,   2756.25 ,   4134.375,
         5512.5  ,   6890.625,   8268.75 ,   9646.875,  11025.   ])
```